# Sharing data between Sinatra condition and request block

Tags: ruby, sinatra, action-filter

I am just wondering if it is possible to have a condition that passes information to the request body once it is complete, I doubt conditions can do it and are the right place even if they could, because it implies they are to do conditional logic, however the authorisation example also redirects so it has a blur of concerns... an example would be something like:

```
set(:get_model) { |body|  { send_to_request_body(Model.new(body)) } }

get '/something', :get_model => request.body.data do
    return "model called #{@model.name}"
end
```

The above is all psudocode so sorry for any syntax/spelling mistakes, but the idea is I can have a condition which fetches the model and puts it into some local variable for the body to use, or do a halt with an error or something.

I am sure filters (before/after) would be a better way to do this if it can be done, however from what I have seen I would need to set that up per route, whereas with a condition I would only need to have it as an option on the request.

An example with before would be:

```
before '/something' do
    @model = Model.new(request.body.data)
end

get '/something' do
    return "model called #{@model.name}"
end
```

This is great, but lets say I now had 20 routes, and 18 of them needed these models creating, I would need to basically duplicate the before filter for all 18 of them, and write the same model logic for them all, which is why I am trying to find a better way to re-use this functionality. If I could do a catch-all Before filter which was able to check to see if the given route had an option set, then that could possibly work, but not sure if you can do that.

In ASP MVC you could do this sort of thing with filters, which is what I am ideally after, some way to configure certain routes (at the route definition) to do some work before hand and pass it into the calling block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions can set instance variables and modify the params hash. For an example, see the built-in [user_agent](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1138-1145) condition.

```
set(:get_model) { |body| condition { @model = Model.new(body) } }

get '/something', :get_model => something do
  "model called #{@model.name}"
end
```

You should be aware that `request` is not available at that point, though.

Comment: Ah that seems like what im after, it feels like a bit of a hack but should be fine for now. When you say I cannot get hold of the request, can I still get hold of the request body via @params[:body] or something? if not then that would be a deal breaker :( however that is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Sorry to post again and this is not 100% on topic, but I wrote some code a while back to check a cookie within a custom conditional, and that seemed to work ok using request.cookies.has_key? "xxxx". That shouldn't have worked if you cannot use request in that scope...

Comment: In the `condition` block, you have access to `request`. However, when the line `get '/something', :get_model => request.body.data` is being evaluated, you don't.

Comment: Oh! yeah sorry thats fine, I was just writing that stuff off top of my head. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sinatra has support for [before and after filters](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Filters):

```
before do
  @note = 'Hi!'
  request.path_info = '/foo/bar/baz'
end

get '/foo/*' do
  @note #=> 'Hi!'
  params[:splat] #=> 'bar/baz'
end

after '/create/:slug' do |slug|
  session[:last_slug] = slug
end
```

Comment: Yep I know that, I mentioned it above. However to do that you need to do 2 route definitions, one for your actual request body block, and one for the before block. I just want one re-usable filter that can be used by everything *if* it has an option defined, will edit the initial post to be clearer on this point.